# Why does my Lenovo Ideapad 100 lag so much?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

It's freezing, causing unexpected errors, it's jittering youtube videos and most of all, applications stop responding often.

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 100 with Intel i3 processor and onboard Intel HD graphics. The display is new because the old one dimmed out/burnt somehow. Maybe some power issues. The battery only lasts me 2.5 hours max when it's unplugged.

I don't know if Microsoft has read the one million error reports I've sent them in the past year alone, but if they have they'd know how an annoying experience I've had using Windows on this laptop.

Is it hardware issue, maybe? What kind of upgrade can I do to this laptop to make it run faster?

What all tweaks do I have to apply right now to it to make it run smoothly?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: also try opening Resource Monitor (open start menu and search, or open task manager > performance > open Resource Monitor) and see what's consuming the resources